# Is BackGroundTasks good option for making network call and send notification in a SwiftUI App

Tags: swift, swiftui, bgtaskscheduler

I am relatively new to Swift and currently writing an app on SwiftUI. My app makes a network call, lists buy/sell orders on different products, showing orders with different quantities and prices. The market is open for 4 hours on weekdays. I want to extend my app and allow users to receive notifications about updates in this market. For example, the user selects to receive notifications when product A has a sell order of price 4 with 5 kg quantity, etc. My app should make network calls in the background in X minutes intervals (maximum of 10) and send notifications to the user if their needs are met. I am researching ways to accomplish this in SwiftUI.

I came across to BackgroundTasks. Is it worth implementing this for this purpose? There are not enough code examples on this on SwiftUI so I have to spend some time to figure it out. I wanted to ask before spending a lot of time because what I understand is that BackgroundTasks are not very reliable when scheduling a task: the system schedules these tasks based on app usage, battery, etc. Since the market is open only for 4 hours I want to make these calls very frequently for 4 hours and then not make it the rest of the day. What other methods would you recommend to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> My app should make network calls in the background in X minutes intervals (maximum of 10)...

This is not possible without using silent push notifications from a server (and even then, they might not all be delivered). What you're describing requires a back-end server to drive the requests and then send a push notification to alert the app that it completed. It cannot be achieved entirely within a stand-alone app. Apps cannot run jobs at fixed intervals.